# how to get SharedPreference's null value in Android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

i have made a sharedpreference method like this in adding values and getting the stored values because i will also be using it in another class for updating the value.

```
public static void addPass(String key, String value, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
public static String getPass(String key, Context context) {
    SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return preferences.getString(key, null);
}
```

and i wanted to use the null value of sharedpreference so i made a code like this

```
password = getPass("name", null);

if ((password.equals(""))){
    if (s.toString().equals("1234")) {
        Intent Menu = new Intent(LogIn.this, Menu.class);
        LogIn.this.startActivity(Menu);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
else {
    realpass = getPass("password", LogIn.this);
    if (s.toString().equals(realpass)) {
        Intent Menu = new Intent(LogIn.this, Menu.class);
        LogIn.this.startActivity(Menu);

    } else {
        Toast.makeText(LogIn.this, "Incorrect Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

if the password is null, the user should input 1234 as a password, else if it is null it will set what's stored in the sharedpreference as a password. 
but using this i will get an error like this:

```
02-06 18:25:25.267 2044-2044/com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso, PID: 2044
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String android.content.Context.getPackageName()' on a null object reference
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferencesName(PreferenceManager.java:375)
        at android.preference.PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(PreferenceManager.java:370)
        at com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso.LogIn.getPass(LogIn.java:195)
        at com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso.LogIn$1.onTextChanged(LogIn.java:55)
        at android.widget.TextView.sendOnTextChanged(TextView.java:7991)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4345)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4199)
        at android.widget.EditText.setText(EditText.java:84)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:4174)
        at com.secsys.gagacamaso.gagacamaso.LogIn$6.onClick(LogIn.java:136)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

line 195 is this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
```

line 55 is this:

```
password = getPass("name", null);
```

thank you so much for anyone who will try to help me out on this, been trying to figure out how to have a default value and update it and store the password the whole day

### EDITED PART

i was able to set the default password to 1234 but when i tried to change the password, i still get 1234 as the password, this is my code from another class the other one is named **LogIn.java**.

### Menu.java

```
ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String oldpassword = oldpass.getText().toString();
                    String newpassword = newpass.getText().toString();
                    if (LogIn.password.equals("")) {
                        if (oldpassword.toString().equals("1234")) {
                            login.getPass("password",Menu.this);
                            login.addPass("password",newpassword,getApplicationContext());
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"New password saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"Old Password is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                    else {
                        if (oldpassword.equals(LogIn.realpass)){
                            login.getPass("password",Menu.this);
                            login.addPass("password", newpassword, getApplicationContext());
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"New password saved!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        else{
                            Toast.makeText(Menu.this,"Old Password is not correct",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: use "" instead of null

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because you are passing a null `Context` to the getPass method.

```
password = getPass("name", null); // <-- Null Context
```

Thus, the following code will crash as shown in the stacktrace:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context); // <-- Null Context
```

Send a proper Application `Context` to it and it will work.

Furthermore, to get what you want you use the [getString](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html#getString(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) like this within the `getPass` method:

```
preferences.getString(key, "");
```

This will get an empty String if the prefs does not exist and your code will work as you're comparing with empty strings after that.

Comment: thank you! preferences.getString(key,"") worked! should i use getApplicationContext() instead of context?

Comment: this should work depending on where you are calling this method `password = getPass("name", getApplicationContext());`

Comment: thank you it did work! i got my default password now as 1234 when the preference is empty, but when i try to add a password to it, when i close and open the app, the password is still 1234 as if the preference is still empty, the toast message "New password saved!" is showing though, i dont know why it wont update

Comment: The lines `login.getPass("password",Menu.this);` before addPass are nonsense and can be erased, As I said, `getApplicationContext()` can be use depending on where you're invoking it. In your case you're under a listener and you may use `Menu.this` instead. The rest should be ok, try to debug the app to see the error better :).

Comment: i thought i still need to get the password and and use the addPass() to update the preference, just using the addPass() will update it eventually? thank you so much for the help though, still trying to figure out why it wont update

Comment: @Ralph No, it won't change anything. What I ment is that the getPass before addPass is nonsense, you don't do anything with the result of getPass. Use addPass with `login.addPass("password", newpassword, Menu.this);` and just after that another line of `String test = login.getPass("password",Menu.this);`. The variable `test` should have the `newpassword` value and in other app runs the same unless you override or delete it (debug the app and put a breakpoint to see if you override it after those two lines).

Comment: yea i understand now, thank you so much! fount out that i set the password in LogIn.java to getPass("name", getApplicationContext()); instead of "password" thanks for your help!